# Correct Spring Cloud+Eureka+Zuul architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring-Cloud based application.

I have two gateway servers behind an HTTP Load balancer. The gateway servers redirect calls to 3 types of backend servers (let's call them UI1, UI2, REST) by querying a Eureka server for an endpoint.

However, if I am understanding the Spring documentation correctly, once a connection has been made between the client and the endpoint, Eureka is no longer needed until a disaster occurs. Client-side load balancing means that the client now has knowledge of an endpoint, and as long as it is working, it will not fetch a new endpoint from Eureka.

This is good in general, but in my setup, the client is actually the Gateway server, not the client browser. The client browser connects to the HTTP load balancer. Everything else is pretty much managed by the gateway.

So, it appears that if I have 2 Gateways and 6 backend servers of each type - I'm not getting any benefits of scalability. Each gateway will take ownership of the first two backend servers per server type, and that's it. The other 4 servers will just hang there, waiting for some timeout or crash to occur on the first 2 servers, so they could serve the next requests.

This doesn't sound like the correct architecture to me. I would have liked Eureka/Client side load balancing to have the ability to do some sort of round-robin or other approach, that would distribute my calls evenly between all servers as much as possible.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you using Ribbon to refer to your resources? You should provide simply the application name registered to Eureka when accessing the service. This will round-robin all requests made to the applications registered in Eureka. An example URI for a REST call might be http://my-registered-service:8000/my-rest-endpoint

Comment: I am purely using @EnableZuulProxy on the gateway, the rest of the configuration is done at application.yml. Relevant section:

    zuul: 
     retryable: true 
     routes:
       ui1-server: /ui1/** 
       ui2-server: /ui2/** 
       api-resource-server: /rest/** 

    eureka:
      client:
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/  
      instance:
          metadataMap:
            instanceId:     ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
Sorry, can't find a way to indent properly here...

Comment: @odedia ribbon, by default, does round robin load-balancing.

Comment: So what is the meaning of client-side load balancing? Am I wrong to assume that once a connection between endpoints is created, Eureka is out of the diagram?